# How do you overcome valid assert test of value modifed by function, in typescript?

Tags: typescript, deno

Here is my typescript code, whcih I run in deno.

```
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std/testing/asserts.ts"

interface Tree{
    size:number
}

let tree: Tree= {
    size: 1
}

let f1 = (tree: Tree)=>{
    tree.size--
}

function main(){
    assert(tree.size === 1)
    f1(tree);
    assert(tree.size === 0);
}
```

When I run it, it gives me this error while compilation at line 20:

```
error: TS2367 [ERROR]: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '1' and '0' have no overlap.
    assert(tree.size === 0);
```

This are valid assertions, but still both IDE and Typescript compiler complains about it.
How do you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into how `assert` function [implemented](https://deno.land/std/testing/asserts.ts#L136), you can see that it uses [assertion signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

The problem is that

> `asserts` ensures that whatever condition is being checked must be true for the **remainder of the containing scope**.

Currently Typescript has no way to know that `f1` modifies/mutates the `tree`. You can read about trade-offs in control flow analysis [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)

---

As a workaround, you can prevent typescript from inferring literal type for `1`:

```
assert(tree.size === 1 as number);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXygGdCQYMAKEADwAcYAueNAa1RwHdUBKRokswvGp0AUCKyoMpRFDAIAKnAQBvEfHXxCWAF4hGqZAFsARqREBfMRBAZ4GJY0UgEAXniqNmnXvgBGC1Y2SL7wbuT2zo5KXC4AfB4aESAAdFq6ALTpASIo6Nh48IZQEuRcCep8pBRJqd6hLm4hRPAGJqRcANxqGoi%204dFdnpVk-c61uvVuAAwEgq2mMJ0WQA)